# Is there any bootstrap 4 class with "cursor:pointer" different than "btn"?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using [bootstrap cards class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) and I want to see the cursor pointer when hovering some card. However, I do not want to use `style` attribute, only bootstrap classes. I know that `btn` class is a possible choice, but it includes `text-align: center` and therefore I have to insert `text-left` to fix the alignment behavior.

Is there any bootstrap 4 option that offer just `cursor :pointer` property?

Comment: You could and should add your own customisations in a seperate CSS file. Additional classes and/or overrides of existing classes. There you could define a class (e.g. `is--pointer`) that does just that `.is--pointer { cursor: pointer; }`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could add `role="button"` to your HTML element, because Bootstrap has the following CSS:

```css
[role=button] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This also has the bonus of adding accessibility hints.

Comment: Simple and clean

Answer (score 3):

You can make the card a `summary` element...

```
<summary class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
       ...
    </div>
</summary>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/QRiBdrBHcL

Comment: Yes, I could use it and it actually works fine, but for me it does not look right from the semantic point of view since the `summary` should be used in the `details` tag;

Comment: True, but this is the *only* other class that Bootstrap 4 provides with the pointer cursor which answers *"Is there any bootstrap 4 class with “cursor:pointer” different than “btn”?"*

Comment: Is it correct to call this a class? After all it is a tag.

Answer (score 2):

for now no cursor:pointer class is in bootstrap.
you have add your own class in cursor pointer

Answer (score 0):

You can use btn-link class along with btn